# How do you publish a picture to an event with facebook opengraph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am able to successfully publish an event to facebook but am unable to include a picture. It looks like this needs to be done via a "connection" in open graph but I can't seem to find a clear example on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the picture connection appears to be read-only.  However it wouldn't hurt to try sending an HTTP Post to /{event id}/picture and seeing if it's just an omission in their API documentation.  My guess is that it is not available.